# How to verify a military TLS certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate, https

I want to try [LPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Portable_Security), but I cannot verify the certificate of their [https site](https://spi.dod.mil/), I already knew the [reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Portable_Security#Public_HTTPS_access), now how can I get the correct certificate information(especially the fingerprint) to compare it to the one I get in the browser?

Edit: I found a site that seems [provide](https://militarycac.com/dodcerts.htm) DOD certificate in https, is that site legit?

Comment: You can’t. Why would anyone publish that? The chain of trust means they don’t have to. You need the CA certificate.

Comment: So it will be impossible for a normal civilian to obtain the CA securely?

Comment: The site is unofficial but legit as far as I know, although not sure how  carefully _they_ check where they've obtained the files... @DanielB, the question _is_ about obtaining the roots as DoD has their own independent from WebPKI, and of course they publish the _public_ root certificates...

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> The web site for distribution of LPS-Public is served over HTTPS, but uses a TLS certificate that is signed by a certificate authority managed directly by the Department of Defense. This CA is not trusted by most non-DoD operating systems and browsers. Because of this, visiting the site or downloading the ISO will generate a browser security warning indicating that the certificate is not trusted. Military-issued devices already include this certificate authority in their list of trusted CAs, and so will not see these errors.

You'll have to get the CA from DOD.

Comment: Apparently, they’re available here: http://iase.disa.mil/pki-pke/Pages/tools.aspx (tab “Trust Store“).

Comment: Nice. Thanks.  I like the toll-free number to verify the fingerprint of the signature.

Comment: @quadruplebucky - What makes you think there is a number you can call to verify the fingerprint of the certificate?  The thumbprint of the certificate is `‎b8 48 bd a3 10 8c 3e b2 42 b2 51 0c 47 9e e0 ab 53 66 2f ed` by the way.  The certificate is valid from `8/22/2016` to `8/23/2018`.  Of course if you download from iase.disa.mil, which itself is a secure connection, I don't understand the concern.

Comment: I think the author was being sarcastic, sarcasm escapes me, I am a very literal person :$

Comment: @Ramhound apparently you're not too literal, because the site for the CAs does indeed have a phone number.

Comment: @DanielB The downloads in that website is not always https, and the few https link still not recognized by a normal browser.

Comment: @Ramhound Where did you get the fingerprint?

Comment: I went to the site, viewed the thumbprint, by viewing the certificate

Comment: @Ramhound Mine is the same as yours, but we still can't say it's perfectly safe right? I'm looking for a reliable way verify it.